# sitecore glass mapper link rendering pipeline

Tags: hyperlink, sitecore, pipeline, mapper, glass-mapper

We have some variable replace code that runs through the sitecore rendering pipeline.  Now that we are using glass mapper, the links (Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Link) are no longer going through the Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.AddBeforeAndAfterValues pipeline.  Is there a way to force it to go through the pipeline or another pipeline I should hook?  Tried IsEditable without luck.  I've also tried Setting = SitecoreFieldSettings.ForceRenderField annotation on the glass interface.  I'm using GlassMapper 4.05

Answer (score 0):

The ForceRenderField setting is only applied to string properties, so you could map your property to a string rather than a Link and use that setting.  If you want to keep your property as a Link, you would probably need to create a custom [Data Mapper](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial19) to run your variable replacement.